# Get key with lowest value

Tags: scala

I am trying to get the key with the lowest value in the following.

The answer should return: 12

```
keyCount.collect()
res14: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((8,33), (15,347), (5,2257), (2,18117), (16,955), (9,33), (3,1126), (12,18), (1,1009), (11,25), (10,397))
```

Would anyone know how I might go about doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@reduce[A1%3E:A](op:(A1,A1)=%3EA1):A1) for example:

```
keyCount.collect().reduce((l, r) => if (l._2 < r._2) l else r)._1
```

or [`minBy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@minBy[B](f:A=%3EB):A)

```
keyCount.collect().minBy(_._2)._1
```